# PrimeFaces editable cell doesn't update the value

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces

So I am trying to use a PrimeFaces data table to set data to a list as follows;

```
<h:form id="frmSalarySupplement">
   <p:panel>
       <p:dataTable id="tblSalarySupplement"
                    value="#{salSupplementMB.dataListFromDB}" 
                    var="salSupp"
                    rowIndexVar="rowSn" 
                    scrollable="true" 
                    rows="10" 
                    paginator="true"
                    editable="true" 
                    editMode="cell" 
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100">

           <p:ajax event="cellEdit" 
                   listener="#{salSupplementMB.onCellEdit}" 
                   update="@this" />

           <p:column headerText="#" escape="false" 
                     style="white-space:pre-line; 
                     word-break:break-all; 
                     width:20px; 
                     text-align:center;">
               <h:outputText value="#{rowSn+1}" />
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Name" 
                     style="white-space:pre-line; 
                     word-break:break-all; 
                     width:250px;">
               <h:outputText value="#{salSupp.empId.name}" />
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Designation" 
                     style="white-space:pre-line; 
                     word-break:break-all; 
                     width:150px;">
               <h:outputText value="#{salSupp.empId.designation.designationName}" />
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Allowance" 
                     style="white-space:pre-line; 
                     word-break:break-all; 
                     width:100px;">
               <p:cellEditor>
                   <f:facet name="input">
                       <h:inputText value="#{salSupp.allowance}" 
                                    style="width:100%" />
                   </f:facet>
                   <f:facet name="output">
                       <h:outputText value="#{salSupp.allowance}" />
                   </f:facet>
               </p:cellEditor>
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Special&#10;Allowance" 
                     style="white-space:pre-line; 
                     word-break:break-all; 
                     width:100px;">
               <p:cellEditor>
                   <f:facet name="input"> 
                       <h:inputText value="#{salSupp.specialAllowance}" 
                                    style="width:100%" />
                   </f:facet>
                   <f:facet name="output">
                       <h:outputText value="#{salSupp.specialAllowance}" />
                   </f:facet>
               </p:cellEditor>
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Transport&#10;Allowance" 
                     style="white-space:pre-line; 
                     word-break:break-all; 
                     width:100px;">
               <p:cellEditor>
                   <f:facet name="input">
                       <h:inputText value="#{salSupp.transportAllowance}" 
                                    style="width:100%" />
                   </f:facet>
                   <f:facet name="output">
                       <h:outputText value="#{salSupp.transportAllowance}" />
                   </f:facet>
               </p:cellEditor>
           </p:column>
       </p:dataTable>
   </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

So I want to be able to save the data I have edited on the cell to set it on the list.  When I do the following, I don't get an updated value.

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
}
```

Can someone suggest what shall I do with it?

**Update**

Also, can anyone tell me why my table loads multiple times when I edit the value?  Maybe that's what's giving me the problem.

Comment: You have a form, right ?

Comment: What is the scope of `salSupplementMB`?

Comment: It's public.  I just cannot get getNewValue() to work.

Comment: I mean what is the [scope](http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes) of the bean `salSupplementMB`?  It might be your problem if none is specified.

Comment: Oh sorry, I miss understood.  It's ViewScoped.

Comment: No problem.  I see in your question edit that you have another weird issue.  Can you share the bean code so we can have a look at it?

Comment: I have decided to go another route, for now.  Maybe I will revisit this on some other date.  Thanks @ForguesR mate.